# Efficient way to insert values in an Oracle SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have two tables like

```
 create table nodes_tbl as (
 select 'a' as nodeid, 'some string' as dummy_string, 0 as subnetid from dual union all
 select 'b', 'qwe', 0 from dual  union all
 select 'c', 'asd', 0  from dual union all
 select 'd', 'zxc', 0 from dual union all
 select 'e', 'rty', 0 from dual);
```

And

```
 create table subnets as (
 select 'a' as nodeid, 1 as subnetid from dual union all
 select 'b', 2 from dual  union all
 select 'c', 2 from dual union all
 select 'd', 3 from dual union all
 select 'e', 4 as nodeid from dual);
```

With several millions of records a join works fast.

```
select  n.NODEID, n.DUMMY_STRING, s.subnetid
   from nodes_tbl n, subnets s where s.nodeid=n.nodeid
```

Writes are fast as well

```
create table test_tbl as  n.NODEID, s.subnetid 
 from nodes_tbl n, subnets s where s.nodeid=n.nodeid  --10M records in 2s.
```

However, when I try to update table and add values to the column the query is very slow

```
      UPDATE nodes_tbl n
       SET subnetid = (SELECT subnetid
                             FROM subnets s
                            WHERE s.nodeid = n.nodeid)
    WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT subnetid  FROM subnets s
                            WHERE s.nodeid = n.nodeid)  --8 minutes for 100K records
```

Why is insert so much slower than a `create table` from a `select` statement?
What is the most efficient way to do this insert?

I know about create view option, but want to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `MERGE` instead:

```
merge into nodes_tbl n
  using (select s.subnetid, s.nodeid 
         from subnets s
        ) x
  on (x.nodeid = n.nodeid)
when matched then update set
  n.subnetid = x.subnetid;
```

Any improvement?

By the way, did you create index on `NODEID` column in both tables?

Comment: Runs at least 500 times faster. Thank you.